# Have multiple ajax request running asynchronously

Tags: ajax, magento, asynchronous

I am working on a magento site and there is a section where you can load products into the cart using ajax.  This works fine but it only allows one request to process at a time.  While one is posting to the database you can not select another product or it will kill that first request.  My question is how (or is it possible) to have multiple requests running simultaneously without one cancelling the other out ?    The action that handles the POST is :

```
public function addAjaxAction()
{   
    $response   = array();
    $error      = false;
    $cart       = $this->_getCart();
    $params     = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if (isset($params['simple_sku']) && $params['simple_sku'] != '') 
        $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($params['simple_sku']));
    else  
        $product    = $this->_initProductInStock();
    $related    = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

    if (!$product) {
        $error = 'Can not add item to shopping cart';
    }else{
        try {
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);                               
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }   
            $cart->save();  
            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete', array('product'=>$product, 'request'=>$this->getRequest()));
            $response['status'] = 'success';
            $response['cart'] =  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/cart_minicart')
                ->setTemplate('page/html/modals/added_to_bag.phtml')
                ->setChild(
                    'breads'                    ,$this->getLayout()->createBlock('modcheckout/cart_breadcrumbs')->setTemplate('page/html/modals/mini_crumb.phtml')
                )
                ->toHtml();
                $response['cartStatus'] = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/status.phtml')->toHtml();
                $response['checkoutNow'] = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkout/cart/checkoutnow.phtml')->toHtml();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $error = 'Can not add item to shopping cart';
        }
    }
    if($error){
        $response['status'] = 'error';
        $response['message'] = $error; /*= $this->getLayout()->createBlock('modcore/messages')
            ->addMessage(new Mage_Core_Model_Message_Error($error))
            ->getGroupedHtml();*/
    }
    echo Zend_Json::encode($response);
}
```

And the js that handles the response :

```
function addQuickviewAjax() {
    if(productForm.validate()){ 
        if(Product<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>.validate()) {                        
            var params = 'product='+Product<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>.productId+'&qty='+Product<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>.currentQty+'&super_attribute[76]='+Product<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>.currentColor+'&super_attribute[491]='+Product<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>.currentSize;
            new Ajax.Request('/modcheckout/cart/addAjax', {
            parameters: params,
                onFailure: reportError, 
                onSuccess: function(transport) {
                    var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                    if(json.status == 'error'){
                        alert (json.message);       
                    } else if(json.status == 'success') {                       
                        alert ('success');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me a bit on all of this and tell me how/if I could have multiple POST using that action ?

Comment: thanks for the link but that just advises to use .live(), a deprecated method and I do not have the luxury of jquery for this project.. I do not really understand how this relates to what I am asking...

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to limit the number of simultaneous requests - so don't send multiple requests, send a single XHR to a multiple-product-add action. For a better idea look at `Mage_Checkout_CartController::addgroupAction()`.